# Opensips With Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, opensips

I am trying to integrate opensips 1.10 with Cassandra 2.0. I want to transfer data from siptrace to Cassandra. Can anyone give the steps or a document to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show a sample of what sip trace output looks like and elaborate on how you would want to query it?

Comment: sample of sip trace output :

http://www.opensips.org/html/docs/db/db-schema-1.4.x.html#GEN-DB-SIP-TRACE

to query it, I would use the following in my opensips config file :

modparam("cachedb_cassandra", "cachedb_url","cassandra:group1://localhost:9061/Keyspace1_Users_Counters");
cache_store("cassandra:group1","key","$ru value");